# Conditional output dependent on position on page

Tags: positioning, koma-script

I want to prepare a collection of small texts (letters, so there is no real headline that could be used as \section) with the scrbook class. Some of these are quite short, so several texts may fit on one page. There should be a separator (I've used a centered parbox containing a horizontal rule and spacing) between two texts. Using the needspace package and `\needspace{5\baselineskip}`
I've made sure that the separator will only be output if there is enough space for the first few lines of the next letter -- otherwise separator and text will be moved to the next page.

That's already part of it what I want to accomplish. The next step is to remove the separator if it would be printed at the top of the next page (meaning the page body, after the header line). Is there a way to determine that the output position is at the top?

Comment: Are there chunk of texts that occupy more than a page?

Comment: @egreg It could happen. Some paragraphs may be up to half a page long, and I also use footnotes. There's a good chance that long paragraphs are footnote-heavy, so that the space for the actual page body is considerably reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `needspace` you can use `\clubpenalties` so that at least three lines of the next paragraph stay in the page.

For the separator, use leaders, that will disappear at a page break.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\newcommand{\separator}{%
  \par
  \vskip 0pt plus 5pt
  \cleaders\vbox to 20pt{\vss\hrule height 1pt width\textwidth\vss}\vskip20pt
  \vskip 0pt plus 5pt
}

% we want at least three lines
\clubpenalties=4 10000 10000 10000 0

\begin{document}

abc\footnote{abc}\footnote{def}\footnote{ghi}%
\lipsum[1]
abc\footnote{abc}\footnote{def}\footnote{ghi}%

\separator

abc\footnote{abc}\footnote{def}\footnote{ghi}
\lipsum[2]
abc\footnote{abc}\footnote{def}\footnote{ghi}%

\separator

abc\footnote{abc}\footnote{def}\footnote{ghi}
\lipsum[3]

\separator

\lipsum[4]

\separator

\lipsum[5]

\separator

\lipsum[6]

\separator

\lipsum[7]

\separator

\lipsum[8]

\separator

\lipsum[9]

\separator

\lipsum[10]

\separator

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to shorten and center the rule, with a less prominent thickness:

```latex
\newcommand{\separator}{%
  \par
  \vskip0pt plus 5pt
  \cleaders\vbox to 20pt{
    \vss
    \moveright 50pt\vbox{\hrule width\dimexpr\textwidth-100pt}
    \vss}
  \vskip20pt
  \vskip0pt plus 5pt
  \nointerlineskip
}
```

Adjust to suit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! And after some hours of reading up on TeX and trying, I've even managed to shorten (that was easy) and center the rule. :-)

Comment: @Andreas I added a not so complicated code to the purpose.

Comment: Thanks! That looks far more elegant and intuitive than my approach: defining the rule as `\def\ruler{\hbox to .1\textwidth{\hfil}\hbox to .8\textwidth{\hrulefill}}` and using that in another hbox inserted into the vbox: `\cleaders\vbox to 30pt{\vss{\hbox{\ruler}}\vss}\vskip30pt`. Moreover, I really didn't like that I had to use `\def` inside a function as the command would be redefined each time the function was called (necessary because \textwidth could change -- or was it \linewidth that depends on the current environment -- minipage, column, parbox etc.?). Using your code now. :-)